# Reading netCDF data in R and converting into one file .txt

Tags: r, merge, netcdf

I'm trying to read 7 meteorological variables that were recorded in 352 separated .cdf files. Each file corresponds to 1440 measurements.

My main problem is that not all files have the 1440 measurements per se, and when I regroup all measurements that I'm performing in my loop, I get an expected error:

```
Error in patm[i, ] = get.var.ncdf(ncdf, "atmos_pressure") :
```

`number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

My question is how can I adapted my loop in order to surpass this obstacle?

Here's a sample of the code I'm using:

Data reading.

```
library(chron)
library(ncdf)
library(ncdf.tools)

files=list.files('C:/Users/XXXX/Documents/R_work/XXXX/XXXX/',pattern='*.cdf',full.names=TRUE) #open all files
```

Loop to merge each variable during the whole period (352)

```
patm=matrix(nrow=length(files),ncol=1440)
tmp=matrix(nrow=length(files),ncol=1440)
rh=matrix(nrow=length(files),ncol=1440)
wspd_a=matrix(nrow=length(files),ncol=1440)
wspd_v=matrix(nrow=length(files),ncol=1440)
wdir_v=matrix(nrow=length(files),ncol=1440)
org_prec=matrix(nrow=length(files),ncol=1440)



for(i in seq_along(files)) {

  ncdf=open.ncdf(files[i])

  patm[i,]=get.var.ncdf(ncdf,"atmos_pressure") #Atmospheric pressure (mbar)

  tmp[i,]=get.var.ncdf(ncdf,"temp_mean") #Temperature mean (ºC)

  rh[i,]=get.var.ncdf(ncdf,"rh_mean") #Relative humidity mean (%)

  wspd_a[i,]=get.var.ncdf(ncdf,"wspd_arith_mean") #Wind speed arithmetic mean (m/s)

  wspd_v[i,]=get.var.ncdf(ncdf,"wspd_vec_mean") #Wind speed vector mean (m/s)

  wdir_v[i,]=get.var.ncdf(ncdf,"wdir_vec_mean") #Wind direction vector mean (º)

  org_prec[i,]=get.var.ncdf(ncdf,"org_precip_rate_mean") #ORG precipitation rate mean (mm/h)


}
```

Converting matrix into single vector form before making the .txt files for each variable.

```
pressure=as.vector(t(patm))

temperture=as.vector(t(tmp))

humidity=as.vector(t(rh))

wind_speed_a=as.vector(t(wspd_a))

wind_speed_v=as.vector(t(wspd_v))

wind_direction_v=as.vector(t(wdir_v))

org_precipitation=as.vector(t(org_prec))
```

Comment: Are you trying to find and fill in the gaps? Could you simply read out the number of columns in each file instead of hard coding the 1440?

Comment: reading the number of columns in each file instead of the 1440 seems to be the most successful way to go but how do I do that in the matrix initial construction? Reading out the number of columns of a variable in each ncdf file.

Comment: You probably still want to keep your matrix to go all the way to 1440 since that's your maximal length, but then you don't have to fill it all the way, using something like:
`patm[i,0:length(netcdf)]=get.var.ncdf(ncdf,"atmos_pressure") #Atmospheric pressure (mbar)`. I'm not sure if you can actually get the length of the netcdf file that easily, but something like that. I have never used `matrix` to initialize arrays, so I also don't know what the empty rows look like. You might have to manually fill them in with something (`-999`, `Null` or something of that order?)

Comment: I think it worked! I just did, e.g., patm=matrix(NA,nrow=n,ncol=1440), then inside the loop patm[i,0:length(ncdf[[8]]$time$vals)]=get.var.ncdf(ncdf,"atmos_pressure") where ncdf[[8]]$time$vals is the dimension of each ncdf file to be read. The only thing that I need now is to create a time vector for plotting my variables. How can I do that inside the loop? I have to save and add the time for each variable each time the loop re-starts. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Cynthia, your previous answer was helpful!